# Azure Logic Apps Order By SQL

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have set an alert on logic apps to run a sql view and format the result in HTML table. The problem is even though I have order by clause, the result in HTML table is not sorted in order.

Also, Is there any way on logic apps, I can create multiple HTML tables with different where conditions from sql query

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say where the problem is without seeing any code.

But only the outermost ORDER BY applies for result sets. So the problem may be where your order by clause is placed. Try ordering your result set just before you bind it to the html table.